# Jquery how to change text background to different color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create different color state when user click the words

my html

```
<a href='#' class='click' id='2'>
   word
</a>

<a href='#' class='click' id='3'>
   second word
</a>
```

I want to switch the text background based on the id.

For example when user clicks `word` -> change background color to yellow click again -> orange and click again -> original (white and transparent). It's 2 states.

Second example when user clicks `second word` -> change background color to yellow click again -> orange, click again -> green and click again -> red and click again ->(white and transparent)  It's 3 states

The color states is based on id attribute.

My codes are like

```
   $('.click').click(function(){
            var states = $(this).attr('id');
            var classname = $(this).attr('class');

            switch (classname){
                case 'click':
                    $(this).attr('class', 'yellow');
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
                break;

                case 'yellow':
                    $(this).attr('class', 'orange');
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
                break;

                case 'orange':
                    $(this).attr('class', 'red');
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
               break;

               case 'red':
                    $(this).attr('class', 'click');
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
               break;
               //add more if I have too…..
            }
        })
```

I am trying to figure out how to switch the color based on the `id` instead of hardcode it. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AWqvW/)

Basically, you can set a global colors array, and then set a data attribute on each link, as well as a max attribute, then on every click the background color will jump to the next color until it hits its max then it restarts the cycle.

JS

```
var colors = ['white', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'];
$('.click').click(function(){
            var states = $(this).data('ci');
            states++;
            if(states > $(this).data('max'))
               {
                   states = 0;
               }
               $(this).data('ci', states);
               $(this).css('background-color', colors[states]);

        })
```

HTML

```
<a href='#' class='click' data-ci='0' data-max="2">
   word
</a>

<br>

<a href='#' class='click' data-ci='0' data-max="3">
   second word
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting an id, I would set a data-attribute of the color and or hex value here is the code snippet:

Here is the html with removed id and added data-color attribute

```
<a href='#' class='click' data-color='#000'>
   Black
</a>

<a href='#' class='click' data-color='green'>
    Green
</a>
```

Here is the javascript that triggers background change:

```
$('.click').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').css('background-color', $(this).data('color')); 
});
```

This example removes the need to edit any javascript when a color changes is needed and or addition of a new color.

Here is an example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/XCr4Q/

Comment: I agree that a `data-*` attribute is the right place to store this, but number `id`s aren't invalid, at least in HTML5 (although I don't suggest using number `id`s anyways)...and no, I didn't downvote you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code listed below to determine what triggered the function, and then lookup what color it has followed by changing it to the new color.

```
idTrigger = event.target.id;
```

Besides that you should also remove the other class, otherwise case one will always be the case. You can do so by using:

```
$(this).removeClass('click');
```

Adding can be done by:

```
$(this).addClass('click');
```

However, I am wondering why you are not just using the jQuery .val() function to store some data. http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

you can try

`.addClass('classname');`

and

`.removeClass('classname');`

let me know if you need a working sample

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 different workflow for different ID 
it will be easy if you use nested switch statement

```
switch (id) {
        case 1:
            switch(color) {
                 case('yellow'):
                      // change color
                      break;
                 case('orange'):
                      // change color
                      break;
                 default:

            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch(color) {
                 case('yellow'):
                      // change color
                      break;
                 case('orange'):
                      // change color
                      break;
                 case('red'):
                      // change color
                      break;
                 default:

            }
            break;
        default:

        }
```